# mpz_t to unsigned long long conversion (gmp lib)

Tags: c, gmp

Is there a way to convert a mpz_t variable to unsigned long long in C?How about the other way around,from ull to mpz_t?The gmp library doesn't support this as ull are part of C99.
I found [this](http://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2005-April/001606.html) but it's in c++,and I don't know how to code in c++.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am surprised there wasn't any mention of mpz_import / mpz_export.

Comment: @MarcGlisse To be fair, I'm not a gmp expert, I was simply trying to do a straightforward translation of the linked C++ code to C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some functions for translating between `unsigned long long` and `mpz_t`. Note that `mpz2ull` will smash your stack if the number is too big to fit into an `unsigned long long`:

```
unsigned long long mpz2ull(mpz_t z)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    mpz_export(&result, 0, -1, sizeof result, 0, 0, z);
    return result;
}

void ull2mpz(mpz_t z, unsigned long long ull)
{
    mpz_import(z, 1, -1, sizeof ull, 0, 0, &ull);
}
```

Comment: Very nice...thanks.I'm not familiar with strtoull,why is its' second argument set to 0?

Comment: @kaiseroskilo: The second argument takes an "end pointer", which (if one is given) is set to the end of the number parsing. That way, you can do error checking: if the end is at the null-terminator, the whole string is a valid number. By passing null (written as 0 in my code here), that's saying that I don't care about the end pointer, because I have blind faith that `gmp_snprintf` will always give valid output. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Getting a segfault on the second function, probably just needs mpz_init(result) after mpz_t result;

Comment: As pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416425/converting-an-ull-to-an-mpz-t there are several issues with this code. The snprintf calls are missing an argument (n and ull are unused). You can't return an mpz_t.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for the heads-up! I'll fix this later tonight.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I've reimplemented these functions using `mpz_export` and `mpz_import`, as you've mentioned. (I've even tested them this time!) Note: `mpz2ull` will smash your stack if the number is too big to fit. This is a feature (albeit one with undefined behaviour, in order to keep the code simple), not a bug. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

These functions should work to convert between mpz_t and signed/unsigned long long.  They should be reasonably fast since they avoid having to do string processing:

```
void mpz_set_sll(mpz_t n, long long sll)
{
    mpz_set_si(n, (int)(sll >> 32));     /* n = (int)sll >> 32 */
    mpz_mul_2exp(n, n, 32 );             /* n <<= 32 */
    mpz_add_ui(n, n, (unsigned int)sll); /* n += (unsigned int)sll */
}

void mpz_set_ull(mpz_t n, unsigned long long ull)
{
    mpz_set_ui(n, (unsigned int)(ull >> 32)); /* n = (unsigned int)(ull >> 32) */
    mpz_mul_2exp(n, n, 32);                   /* n <<= 32 */
    mpz_add_ui(n, n, (unsigned int)ull);      /* n += (unsigned int)ull */
}

unsigned long long mpz_get_ull(mpz_t n)
{
    unsigned int lo, hi;
    mpz_t tmp;

    mpz_init( tmp );
    mpz_mod_2exp( tmp, n, 64 );   /* tmp = (lower 64 bits of n) */

    lo = mpz_get_ui( tmp );       /* lo = tmp & 0xffffffff */ 
    mpz_div_2exp( tmp, tmp, 32 ); /* tmp >>= 32 */
    hi = mpz_get_ui( tmp );       /* hi = tmp & 0xffffffff */

    mpz_clear( tmp );

    return (((unsigned long long)hi) << 32) + lo;
}

long long mpz_get_sll(mpz_t n)
{
    return (long long)mpz_get_ull(n); /* just use unsigned version */
}
```

The function signatures are supposed to look like native GMP functions.
As with other `gmpz_set_` functions, these assume the variables passed have been initialised already, but it is easy to change them into `gmp_init_set_` style functions.