# Is there a portable method of converting a `uintmax_t` to a `mpz_t`?

Tags: gmp

Is there a portable method of converting a `uintmax_t` to a `mpz_t`?

Compiling the following code with clang on OSX fails because there is no constructor for uint64_t for mpz_class.

```
const mpz_class maxUint64 = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
```

> error: conversion from 'type' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'const mpz_class' (aka 'const __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>') is ambiguous
>      static const mpz_class maxUint64 = std::numeric_limits::max();

Comment: If all else fails, you can always go via `string`.

Comment: Do you mean uintmax_t or uint64_t? If long is the same size as long long on your system, you can use that instead. Otherwise, it gets more complicated. For instance split the 64 bits into 32+32, convert the high part, shift it left, and add_ui the low part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mpz\_t to unsigned long long conversion (gmp lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248723/mpz-t-to-unsigned-long-long-conversion-gmp-lib)