# GMP - Store 64 bit interger in mpz_t/mpz_class and get 64 bit integers back

Tags: c++, integer, 64-bit, assign

I want to assign the values from 64 bit integers into `mpz_class`/`mpz_t` variables and later get 64 bit integers back. However GMP only provides this functionality for 32 bit and lower integers.

So how would I turn an 64 bit integer into a `mpz_class`/`mpz_t` variable and vice versa. (I need it for both signed and unsigned integers)

Comment: Maybe it could be done using `mpz_import` and `mpz_export`?

Comment: Excuse my stupid question, but for what is `rop` and `op`? Which of these recieves the value? And also with just one value the endianness shouldn't matter, right? This seems to work fine with unsigned ints, but what about signed ints? Edit: I now understand the difference between `rop` and `op`

Comment: I will create an answer for you :)

Comment: @BrainStone Endianess matters since your values are 8 bytes, just pick 0 for 'native' endianess

Comment: @john you are right. I meant the order (parameter). That really shouldn't matter, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I guess you are on windows? On other 64 bit OS, GMP does handle 64 bit integers (the interface uses `long`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6248723/1918193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved with [`mpz_import()` and `mpz_export()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html) functions.
Code sample (tested on LP64 data model):

```
using Type = int64_t;

// We start with some 64bit integer
const Type builtIn64 = std::numeric_limits<Type>::min();
std::cout << builtIn64 << '\n';

// Import the integer into the mpz_class
mpz_t mpzNum;
mpz_init(mpzNum);
mpz_import(mpzNum, 1, 1, sizeof(Type), 0, 0, &builtIn64);
if (builtIn64 < 0) {
    mpz_neg(mpzNum, mpzNum);
}
std::cout << mpz_class(mpzNum) << '\n';

// Export the mpz_t value to a buffer allocated by the function and given
// the word size, get also the number of words required to hold the value
const size_t wordSize = sizeof(Type);
size_t wordCount = 0;
void* outRaw = mpz_export(nullptr, &wordCount, 1, wordSize, 0, 0, mpzNum);

// Make sure that our integer type can still hold the value
if (wordCount == 1) {
    const Type out = *static_cast<Type*>(outRaw);
    std::cout << out << '\n';
}

// Free the allocated memory by mpz_export
void (*freeFunction)(void*, size_t);
mp_get_memory_functions(nullptr, nullptr, &freeFunction);
freeFunction(outRaw, wordCount * wordSize);

// Don't forget to free the allocated memory
mpz_clear(mpzNum);
```

---

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54696e0d679d438a)

Comment: Since `mpz_export` returns an `uint64_t` array in this case, couldn't we just check the wordCount and if it's 1 just have `out = allocated[0]; delete[] allocated;`?

Comment: @BrainStone You are absolutely right, I've edited the answer. However, keep in mind that you cannot use `delete[]` to free the memory allocated by `mpz_export` as it is certainly not using `new` to allocate the memory. You cannot mix `new` with `free` and `malloc` with `delete`. It's much safer to get the `free()` function using the API.

Comment: @BrainStone I'm still looking in a way to tell `mpz_t` that it is a signed value. It works when you convert the `int64_t` to `mpz_t` and back, but `mpz_t` itself doesn't seem to handle the value as signed.

Comment: thank you! Also from what I read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013661/1996022 it's better to use a `static_cast` here, since we know the `void*` is in reality a `uint64_t*` (or at least the words have the same size)

Comment: Yep, you are right, the condition `wordCount == 1` makes it possible :)

Comment: Got it working even with the negative numbers, see my edit ;-)

Comment: The `to_mpz_t` seems to have a [bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a44ced6acc822056). Consider fixing.

Comment: @pmor Has been a few years, what bug have you bumped into with the code?

Comment: Have you opened the link? Here is another [example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed1ea814e5771344). Briefly: `to_mpz_t` may store to `out` wrong value.